# Javascript - Is there a way to export HTML along with formatting to a word document using ActiveX?

Tags: javascript, html, ms-word, activex, activex-documents

I figured out a way to write to word using an ActiveX component but I am not sure if its possible to write HTML to Word,

```
function generateWord(elementIdValue){

  var value=$("#"+elementIdValue)).html();

  var word= new ActiveXObject('Word.Application');
  word.Visible=true;
  var doc=word.Documents.Add();
  var sel=word.Selection;
  sel.TypeText(value);

}
```

I don't want to save HTML directly to word (It wouldn't be readable with all html tags), rather want to write the data along with HTML styling in word.

I had successfully written HTML to Outlook along with formatting using HTMLBody property,

```
var objO = new ActiveXObject('Outlook.Application');     
var objNS = objO.GetNameSpace('MAPI');     
var mItm = objO.CreateItem(0);     
mItm.To = "";
mItm.Subject = "Test";
mItm.HTMLBody = (($(("#"+elementIdValue)).html())
```

Is there a property in word object similar to Outlook object that can consume HTML?

Comment: Grabbing the HTML does not mean you'll get the associated styling with it. What is your goal?

Comment: My goal is to maintain formatting when writing to word document. I am trying to achieve same effect as copying the html data and pasting to word (this will just paste the data along with formatting).

Comment: It will never work. The MS Word HTML rendering engine is absolute crap. You're better of generating a PDF.

Comment: It's always worked for me to use a full HTML document as the contents of a Word Doc. To see for yourself, essentially just change the file extension from .html to .doc(x)... Word will render it the very best it can.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it without using ActiveX. Check [this](http://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Export-Html-To-Word-Document-With-Images-Using-jQuery-Word-Export-Plugin.html).